# How can I check if string is velocity code

Tags: java, velocity

For example, I've got HTML code

```
            <table>
     <!-- #if($!item.get('specialPrice') && $!item.get('specialPrice')!= "")-->
     <!-- [if mso]-->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                      Hello world
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Here I need to remove comment with content  `<!-- [if mso]-->` which is not velocity and velocity code `<!-- #if($!item.get('specialPrice') && $!item.get('specialPrice')!= "")-->` should stay

So the question is how to correctly identify velocity code?

Comment: What is velocity code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one thing that comes into my mind is to remove it using regex (assuming every velocity statements start with either # or $)

e.g

```java
var r = "<!-- [^#$].*-->";
var t = "<table>\n<!-- #if($!item.get('specialPrice') && $!item.get('specialPrice')!= \"\")-->\n<!-- [if mso]-->\n<tr>\n<td>\n                      Hello world\n</td>\n</tr>\n</table>";

var c = t.replaceAll(r, "something");
System.out.println(c);
```

Should outputs

```
<table>
<!-- #if($!item.get('specialPrice') && $!item.get('specialPrice')!= "")-->
something
<tr>
<td>
                      Hello world
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```